How to ask Cypress to run a check-wait loop until a DOM element has changed?
I recently asked this question about how to detect DOM changes that result from a page operation. I received an excellent answer based on the as() device to capture state.
Here is a working test based on that answer:
visitCountryPage();

// Captures the state of the trip ideas as a static var
getTripIdeas().as('initialValues', { type: 'static' });

// Opens the filter menu
cy
    .get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer button')
    .first()
    .click();

// Now choose a filter option, so the ideas change
cy
    .get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer label[for="experiencesrelax"]')
    .click()
    // @todo I wonder if we can do better than this wait?
    .wait(3000);

// Capture the ideas again
getTripIdeas().as('finalValues', { type: 'static' });

cy.get('@initialValues').then(initial => {
    cy.get('@finalValues')
        .invoke('toArray') // change JQuery<HTMLElement> to HTMLElement[]
        .should('not.deep.eq', initial.toArray())
});

A quick run-through of what is happening:

Visit the page
Snapshot a grid of results called "trip ideas"
Open a pop-up menu
Select a filter option in the menu
Wait a few seconds for the page to change 
Snapshot the grid of results again
Check the two snapshot are different

Readers may also wish to see how I retrieve trip ideas, which is what changes on the click of a specific menu option:
/**
 * Grabs a grid of items (e.g. a set of cards) based on a CSS expression
 */
export function getTripIdeas(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {
    return getGridElements(
        '#sharedTrips section .container div:last-child .card-layout div.column'
    );
}

/**
 * General CSS chainable function
 */
function getGridElements(cssSelector: string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {
    return cy
        .get('body')
        .find(cssSelector);
}

Now eagle-eyed readers will see that I have used a wait() device to let an AJAX operation do its work before the "after" capture is done. But of the little that I have learned about Cypress, it seems it is considered more idiomatic to let Cypress do wait-checking. In other words, we say to Cypress: "I am expecting this change to happen, please wait up to {long wait} for it to happen". This approach allows us to set a long timeout (e.g. 15 seconds) and succeed an assertion quickly (e.g. in three seconds).
Now if this was PHP/Selenium I'd use a wait device like so:
protected function waitUntil(callable $callback, string $reason, $timeout = 10): void
{
    $now = microtime(true);
    do {
        usleep(500 * 1000); // 0.5sec
        $withinTimeout = (microtime(true) - $now) < $timeout;
        $passedTest = $callback($this->getDriver());
    } while ($withinTimeout && !$passedTest);

    if (!$passedTest) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            sprintf('Failed to wait for %s', $reason)
        );
    }
}

And then I call it with something like this:
// Wait for the suggestions to populate
$this->waitUntil(
    function(RemoteWebDriver $driver) {
        try {
            // Ideally we'd make these CSS expressions a bit more specific
            $ideas = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector(
                '#sharedTrips section .container div:last-child .card-layout div.column'
            ));
            // On first load there is currently 8
            return count($ideas) > 4;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    'trip ideas to populate'
);

(Note that here I am merely illustrating how I might do a repeated DOM check in a synchronous language. For clarity, this is not an example of checking that the DOM element contents have changed).
This makes a lot more sense to my non-Promise-aligned brain: keep testing something in the DOM every 0.5 sec until it succeeds or times-out. Can something similar be done in Cypress so that tests are made robust without excessive fixed sleeps?

In regards to the behaviour of the app under test. When the cards are changing (request in flight/still loading), do the old ones get immediately removed when the filter dropdown changes (so a little before the new ones eventually arrive); or are they atomically swapped out "in place" when the new ones arrive (meaning the old ones stick around whilst the request is in flight)?

Good question @adsy. If I get a failure here (i.e. without a sleep) a screenshot shows that the old ones are still in place. They are replaced with the results once they arrive, a few seconds later.

(Thus, the test fails here because it looks like the click did not do anything, when of course the human observer knows that the change would have happened if we had waited a bit longer.)

The .should() command is designed to make previous query retry, you just increase the timeout, which is why it's a bit difficult to understand what your issue is.

Maybe English isn't first language -  "Chai conditionals" would be assertions, "Dom changed condition" could mean the card element is expected to changed - it's a bit hard to tell.

@Karen.Schlossberg: as I understand it, the test phrases such as have.length come from Chai.JS. So, yes, "Chai conditionals" makes perfect sense, but maybe it is not well known where these strings come from? You are quite right that "DOM changed condition" is a reference to the practice of checking that the DOM has changed.

The WebDriver code is performing a different test to the Cypress code. If you just want to count elements before and after the filter action, it's a whole lot easier.
This is my filter simulation. I'm removing one of the <li> elements 5 seconds after clicking the button.
<body>
  <ul>
    <li id="1">one</li>
    <li id="2">two</li>
    <li id="3">three</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="filter()">filter</button>
  <script>
    function filter() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // simulate a filter
        const li = document.getElementById('2')
        li.remove()  
      }, 5000)
    }
  </script>
</body>

The test is just:
it('waits for the element count to change', () => {
  cy.get('li').should('have.length', 3)
  cy.contains('button', 'filter').click()
  cy.get('li', {timeout:6000}).should('have.length', 2)
})


This is really nice and clean when compared to the Selenium code you posted.
All you need to do is specify the state of the page before and after the action, there's no need for the waitUntil loop since that is built into the Cypress runner.
To illustrate, change the the final assertion to a callback and log the element length to dev console.
cy.get('li', {timeout:6000})
  .should($els => {
    console.log('count: ', $els.length)
    expect($els.length).to.eq(2)
  })

The dev console shows 188 calls to the callback, passing on the last one


Using a production DB copy as the test fixture
When your test system is a copy of the production DB, you can't guarantee the contents of specific elements.
In the example above the element count can be anything, so you want to compare initial count and final count.
cy.get('li')
  .then($initial => {
    const initialCount = $initial.length

    cy.contains('button', 'filter').click()

    cy.get('li')
      .its('length', {timeout:6000})
      .should('be.lessThan', initialCount)
  })



Checking element references
Since there was some confusion about what was getting tested in my previous answer, here is a better example.
cy.get('li').eq(1)               // 2nd item
  .then($initial => {

    cy.contains('button', 'filter').click()

    cy.get('li')
     .eq(1, {timeout:6000})
     .should($final => {
        const initialElement = $initial.get(0)
        const finalElement = $final.get(0)
        const elementHasChanged = initialElement !== finalElement
        assert(elementHasChanged, 'element has changed')
     })
  })


If I comment out the click() the test fails (i.e ensuring this doesn't give a false positive).

Testing the complete element list:
cy.get('li')
  .then($initial => {

    cy.contains('button', 'filter').click()

    cy.get('li', {timeout:6000})
      .should($final => {
        const initialElements = $initial.toArray()
        const finalElements = $final.toArray()
        expect(initialElements).to.not.deep.eq(finalElements)
     })
  })


Ah, sorry, my PHP example was not a good steer. I posted that to show a routine that repeatedly-tests-until, rather than the specific test it was making (this specific test is "have ideas loaded"). The Selenium test to do the "have ideas changed yet" would still be a repeated array comparison on headings extracts from jQuery objects.

So yes, if we could do just element count comparisons, your Cypress sample with should have.length is great (and very readable). But your "Checking element references" sample is probably going to be necessary. I am pleased this is possible in Cypress, but my brain is fighting it far more than retaining control of a test loop!

Incidentally, your other answer is excellent, and I would urge you to undelete it. The content and the comments will be valuable to future readers.

The thing is my first answer wasn't correct, it compared jQuery wrappers instead of the elements on the page. The revised version here corrects that issue. I will also add an example that compares the whole list.

Aside from that I was too focused on the technical mistake given in the answer to your previous question, not on the core question. I've make the correction on that answer.

Fair enough, well thanks Eddy. This is, again, very helpful. I will have some time on Wednesday to try this.

Thank you again Eddy, this was perfect. Not only has it solved the problem, but it feels more inuitive than the as() device, which felt like it eschewed JavaScript variables unnecessarily. I have added my solution in a parallel answer.

A follow-up question: what is the origination of the habit to use $ prefixes for variables in JavaScript? I am in that practice for PHP, but it feels a little esoteric for JavaScript. Is it a jQuery practise specifically?

Eddy, you may be interested to see I've asked a Cypress performance question.

Building on Eddy's excellent answer, this was my solution:
visitCountryPage();

getTripIdeas().then($initial => {

    // Opens the filter menu
    cy
        .get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer button')
        .first()
        .click();

    // Now choose a filter option, so the ideas change
    cy
        .get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer label[for="experiencesrelax"]')
        .click();

    getTripIdeas().should($final => {
        const initialElements = $initial.toArray();
        const finalElements = $final.toArray();
        expect(initialElements).to.not.deep.eq(finalElements);
    });
});

Since my getTripIdeas returns a Cypress.Chainable, it works with both .then and .should. As one would expect, removing the click does indeed cause the query to fail, so the not.deep.eq is working correctly.
